# file_get_contents not working with non english filenames in DRUPAL

Tags: php, drupal

I have a problem.
file_get_contents and other file functions (like file, fopen, glob etc) not working when i try to get file with non english symbols. I getting error that file not exist. It is going when i using any of that functions from my simple drupal module. But same time when i try to use file_get_contents outside drupal's code (just created separated php file) this function work as it should.

Can you advice something?? What drupal doing so i can't use file functions on file with non english name from my module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you urlencode() your filename? If not, you need to.

Comment: thanks, it helped. Urldecode helped actually but you give me right way to move.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) module, I believe it will help you a lot. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> Provides one-way string transliteration (romanization) and cleans file names during upload by replacing unwanted characters.
>
> Generally spoken, it takes Unicode text and tries to represent it in US-ASCII characters (universally displayable, unaccented characters) by attempting to transliterate the pronunciation expressed by the text in some other writing system to Roman letters.
>
> According to Unidecode, from which most of the transliteration data has been derived, "Russian and Greek seem to work passably. But it works quite bad on Japanese and Thai."